# How to Create Square shape programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I am making Buttons in LinearLayout programmatically. Please see below code :

```
My LinearLayout in my .xml file :

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/outerRelativeLayout_relativeLayout2_making_dynamically"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Programmatically i am making buttons like :

```
LinearLayout outerRelativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.outerRelativeLayout_relativeLayout2_making_dynamically);
Button imgBtn = new Button(MyActivity.this);


imgBtn.setId(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

imageViewParams.setMargins(0, 10, 10, 10);

outerRelativeLayout.addView(imgBtn, imageViewParams);
```

Here `c.getString(0);` means values comes from local database like 1,2,3...

This lyout looking like attached image : 
[image]

On above image orange colored is LinearLayout and rounds are buttons which are programmaticaly created.

Now i want to do : when any round button clicked then a white colored square on that button should be created like to be mention which button is selected., i know about `View` but i cant understand how to use it to achieve what i want. Can anybody please tell me how to do it ? Hope i explain well my issue....

For Example : When Third Button(in image green round a)clicked... it should be look like this image mean to show that right now green round button is selected:

[image]

Comment: where do you set the colors of the rings of the buttons? i don't see it.

Comment: its is just images, i ddnt it set programmaticaly...

Comment: Hello, The all rings in diff colors are only images not i have set it prorammatically, Like Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s_circle_black);

Comment: ahh ok, now at least i get your idea!! :)

Comment: thanks...do u have any technique to how to i achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is:

Instead of doing it programatically you can have two images on the button, normal and Onclick.

So when the button is clicked the image changes.

For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonclick" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonclick" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>

 </selector>
```

Or Else:

You just have to change the coordinates programatically to make it a square.

But i prefer using the first Solution.

Comment: Actually I want to make square on that round button, like only do show which round button currently selected, not to change whole button

Comment: Yes you can do that with the above mention code. You just need is two images one round and one square. Then instead of "@drawable/buttonclick" you have to use "@drawable/squarebtn" and instead of "@drawable/button" you have to use "@drawable/roundbtn".

Comment: It will work the same way you want it like when the button is clicked it turns into square and back to round correct??

Comment: all you need is make a .xml file and place it in drawable and what ever Onclick you have will be the same. You just have to remove/comment all your code. Try and let me knw if it works and dont forget to accept the answer and an upvote.